# EmguCV/OpenCV QueryFrame slow/buffers

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

We have an application, where we get a message from an external system and then we take a picture, do some processing and return something back to the external system. Doing some performance testing, I found two problems (they are somewhat related). I was hoping someone will be able to explain this to me.

1) Does `_capture.QueryFrame()` buffer frames?
What we see is, if there is a gap between the query for two frames from a web camera, the second frame is often an older picture and not the one when the queryFrame was called.

We were able to mitigate this problem to some extent by discarding some frames, i.e. calling `_capture.QueryFrame()` 2-3 times and discarding the results.

2) The second issue is when we timed different parts of the application, we found that clearing the buffer (calling `QueryFrame()` 2-3 times and not using the results) takes about 65ms and then this line: `Image<Bgr, Byte> source = _capture.QueryFrame()` takes about 80ms. These two parts take the biggest chunk of processing time, our actual processing takes just about 20-30ms more.

Is there a faster way (a) to clear the buffer (b) to capture the frame?

If you have experience with OpenCV and know of something related, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [System.TypeInitializationException using Emgu.CV in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514715/system-typeinitializationexception-using-emgu-cv-in-c) and having tested the various possibilities to acquire an up to date frame I found the bellow the bes method.

1) yes when you set up a Capture from a webcam a ring buffer is created to store the images in this allows effcient allocation of memory.

2) yes there is a faster way, Set your Capture device up globally and set it of recording and calling ProcessFrame to get an image from the buffer whenever it can. Now change your QueryFrame simply to copy whatever frames its just acquired. This will hopefully stop your problem of getting the previous frame and you will now have the most recent frame out of the buffer.

```
private Capture cap;
Image<Bgr, Byte> frame;

public CameraCapture()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cap= new Capture();
    cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
    cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);

    Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
}

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
    grayFrame = frame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
}

public Image<Bgr,byte> QueryFrame()
{
    return frame.Copy();
}
```

I hope this helps if not let me know and I'll try and tailor a solution to your requirements. Don't forget you can always have your acquisition running on a different thread and invoke the new QueryFrame method.

Cheers

Chris

Comment: How about on a console application: there is no Application.Idle event? How could the capture be done?

Comment: Hi Tony, You have two option either use a timer however this limits the frame rate, or simply start a new thread with while(true){frame = _capture.QueryFrame(); } so you have an independent thread capturing images. You may need to add access handlers or a small delay in there but it should work, Cheers

Comment: Thank you! The idea of a new Thread was very nice. I put it here on the console appplication and now it worked.

Comment: How can I contact you? Can you put in your profile your email or website?

Comment: Hi, the easiest way to get hold of me is through the emgu forums http://www.emgu.com/forum/ under the tag of Chris_Johnson , Cheers

Comment: @Chris Do you have an example on the EMGU website whereby you capture on a separate thread?  Right now I use the ImageGrabbed event but I am worried that can effect UI performance.  This was how your example did it though.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, gonzobrains in the newer versions of EMGU the images are captured from it's individual thread there are examples here : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Capture http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Code_Reference

Comment: As in the latest version there is a event for the Capture class called ImageGrabbed which occurs every time an image was grabbed from the camera. This is by far the best solution

Answer (score 0):

This could also be due to the refresh rate of the webcamera you are using. My camera works at 60Hz so I have a timer that takes captures a frame every 15 milliseconds.